# Convert a batch of jrxml files into jasper files?

Tags: maven

How to create a maven target to convert a batch of jrxml files into jasper files which are in the same folder?
The folder path can be the input argument of the command?

Answer (score 1):

```
**- A full example of POM file.**
Command to Build All **Jrxml** to **Jasper File** in maven
If you used eclipse then right click on the project and Run as maven Build and add goals antrun:run@compile-jasper-reports 
compile-jasper-reports is the id you gave in the pom file.

**<id>compile-jasper-reports</id>**
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test`jasper</groupId>
  <artifactId>testJasper</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>TestJasper</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-jasper-reports</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="Start compile of jasper reports" />
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/reports"/>
                            <echo message="${basedir}/src/main/resources/jasper/jasperreports" />
                            <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"
                                classpathref="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                <jrc srcdir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/jasper/jasperreports" destdir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/jasper/jasperclassfile"
                                  xmlvalidation="true">
                                <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                                <include name="**/*.jrxml" />
                            </jrc>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify configuration as below

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/reports</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/reports</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration> <!--  like here -->

                    <executions>
                        <!-- We need to wait until after the java classes have been compiled 
                            to compile the reports -->
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                            <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
                            <exclusions>
                                <exclusion>
                                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                                </exclusion>
                            </exclusions>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

See this post. It specifies the same.
http://kaleeswaran14.blogspot.com/2012/05/compile-jasper-reports-with-maven.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. The problem with simply providing a link as an answer is that the link may go stale and this answer then has no lasting value. Please edit this to actually provide the "how to" details.